# Switching between partial forms using radio inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ejs

I have this template that depending on which radio input is clicked the form changes. The teacher-signup-form is checked by default.

```
<!-- when user clicks either teacher or student a different partial will render in view
    each partial is wrapped in its own form element -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="d-flex flex-row mt-5 mb-5">
            <h2 style="font-family: 'champagne-limo';" class="">General Information:</h2>
    </div> <!--teacher-student checkboxes -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <h5>You are:</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <input checked name="teacher-student" type="radio" id="teacher-signup">
            <label for="teacher-signup">Teacher</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <input type="radio" name="teacher-student" id="student-signup">
            <label for="student-signup">Student</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!--this partial would have the id of 'teacher-signup-form' -->
<%-include("./partials/teacher-signup.ejs")%>

<!--this partial would have the id of 'student-signup-form' -->
<%-include("./partials/student-signup.ejs")%>
```

In my jQuery, I created a simple function that should switch the forms

```
$('#student-signup-form').hide();

  $('#input[name="teacher-student"]:radio').on('change', function(){

    $('#teacher-signup-form').hide();
    $('#student-signup-form').show();
  })

});
```

Unfortunately this does not work and shows both forms for a few seconds then hides the student-signup-form.

Is there a more cleaner efficient way to do this? My jQuery seems like it isn't the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a few changes.  First to hide the student-signup-form on page load you could add the css to do so.

```
#student-signup-form { display: none; }
```

Then in order to allow the toggle back and forth from student and teacher, what I would suggest is you give each form a class of `signup-form` in addition to the ids they have.  Then your radio buttons could be changed to something like the following.

```
<input type="radio" name="teacher-student" class="signup-radio" id="teacher-signup" data-target="#teacher-signup-form" checked>
<input type="radio" name="teacher-student" class="signup-radio" id="student-signup" data-target="#student-signup-form">
```

Then you can generalize the change handler for the form class and the data element on the radios.

```
//cache the forms lookup
var $signupForms = $('.signup-form');
$('.signup-radio').on('change', function(e){
    var $this = $(e.target);

    //hide the forms that do not match the target selector
    $signupForms.not($this.data('target')).hide();
    //show the form that matches the target selector
    $signupForms.filter($this.data('target')).show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the initial state based on static CSS. Otherwise while the page is loading you will see both.

So set style display:none on the student partial.

Then your JS would just become

```
$('#input[name="teacher-student"]:radio').on('change', function(){
  $('#teacher-signup-form').toggle();
  $('#student-signup-form').toggle();
  })
});
```